# NextJS's JSX Transform's add-missing-react-import codemod contradicts React's removing-unused-react-imports codemod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

On NextJS's doc [add-missing-react-import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/codemods#add-missing-react-import) , it mentions to run the codemod to add `import React from "react";` for JSX Transform capabilities. However, on ReactJS's blog [removing-unused-react-imports](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#removing-unused-react-imports) , they mention removing the "extra" `import React` if its found in the file since its unnecessary for JSX Transforms. Which one is correct?

Asked identical question on NextJS's github - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/24877